# How to open a word document without resolving the attached template?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

Due to a Migration from Office 2000 to Office 2010 my word templates names has changed (from *.dot to *.dotm). Now I want to update the declaration of attached templates specified in existing documents.
I wrote a little procedure for mapping "old" and "new" template names, but run into trouble with retrieving the old template name.
When opening the documents with `Documents.open()`, the specified attached template couldn't be found, so Normal.dotm is applied as default and my mapping doesn't work. I didn't find a way to shut down the automatic resolving of attached templates.
Strange behavior: after opening the document the original template name can be seen at the documents properties but `?ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate` is 'Normal.dotm'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MsgBox Dialogs(wdDialogDocumentStatistics).Template
```

Comment: `Dialogs(wdDialogDocumentStatistics).Template` has the path of the template the document once was created. With that info my mapping works now. Thanks. BTW: Word looks for the documents template 1. the creation location 2. the folder the document is saved in 3. the specified folders for user / workgroup templates